# Am I using the WCF service correctly to receive data from client and store it in database?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have already defined a service contract and the operations are implemented. This is 1 example of a service which I implemented:

```
public int CreateIncident(string incidentName, string location, DateTime timeStamp)
{

    //Initilise db object to reference incidentDB database
    incDBEntities db = new incDBEntities();

    int incId = db.Incidents.Max(i => i.incId);

    // Create new record with incremented incident id and assigned fields 
    Incident inc = Incident.CreateIncident(++incId);

    inc.description = incidentName;
    inc.location = location;
    inc.whenReported = timeStamp;

    //Add the incident instance and save changes/updates made to database
    db.AddToIncidents(inc);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return inc.incId;
}
```

The client makes a call to this service with data as arguments.

Is it OK to assign the arguments to data fields and store the data in database?
At the moment I'm successfully able to send data locally through the WCF Test client and get it stored in the database.

I'm not defining data contracts. So I'm not sure if the service will work when remote clients make calls from a android or Microsoft app.

Comment: Try to ask a more specific question. This is pretty vague.

Comment: Ok well, I tried making it more specific. I would appreciate it if someone can give some answer/advice.

Comment: I guess it is OK, as long as you add some level of security to your service, so that you don't get unwanted inserts to your database.

Comment: Alright, I may use WSHttpBinding with security modes set. Can the client then make calls to the service (like above) for adding data from an android app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define data contracts when you're only using primitive types as parameters. They are considered to have default contracts. If you want to use a complex type as a parameter, it must be a DataContract. If the number of parameters gets large (say over 4), or you want to group related parameters, you might want to encapsulate them into a custom type, which would then have to be a DataContract.

Some people like to always use DataContracts, even if they only have one parameter. This can make life easier later when you want to add a parameter to the operation. You just have to add it to the data contract class, instead of changing every call, plus the service contract interface and the class implementing it. It's a matter of personal preference.

As for storing your data, you might want to have your data access layer (`incDBEntities`) as a class member which you instantiate only once, rather than every time an operation is called.

Comment: Ah right, I'm understanding it now, the tutorials and explanation on msdn didn't make sense for my application with wcf service.

Comment: Well I had a look at WCF data service, would that be more efficient and useful for me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "WCF data service".

Comment: WCF data service aka. ADO.NET Data services. It is also called OData Service. I'm wondering if creating data service is more useful for my purposes? I think I will just stick with WCF service as Data service seems confusing to use now.